# jquery # colour to rgba?

Tags: jquery, colors, rgb

Is it possible to convert a colour as such `#ff0000` to rgb?

So convert `#ff0000` to `rgb(255,0,0);`

I'm pretty sure this has got to be possible, I just don't know how. Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use:

```
var s = "#ff0000";
var patt = /^#([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})$/;
var matches = patt.exec(s);
var rgb = "rgb("+parseInt(matches[1], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[2], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[3], 16)+");";
alert(rgb);
```

Comment: Very good. Care to take a minute or 2 to edit and explain how this works exactly? I'm not one for just 'copying and pasting' the final outcome.

Comment: Why not use `var patt = /^#([\dA-F]{2})([\dA-F]{2})([\dA-F]{2})$/i;` ?

Comment: @tfbox, sure. I'm using regex to match a string that looks like `#` followed by six hexadecimal digits. It groups them into groups of 2 and in this case `matches[1]` becomes `ff` while matches 2 and 3 become `00`. The built in `parseInt` function takes a radix as a second parameter, so I just specify hexadecimal (base 16) and it does the work converting to an int.

Comment: @tfbox You should note that `matches[1-3]` will be undefined if the input string is not a 6 hexadecimal digits immediately following a # with no padded spaces on either end or anything, and I don't do any error checking for this. I just assuming it's already known that the input string is valid.

Answer (score 6):

`.css("background-color")` will return rgb http://api.jquery.com/css/

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/msRqv/1/

Comment: Hmm, close. But not 'exactly' what I'm after. I should of mentioned I would want to also be able to apply the alpha channel onto this as well.

Comment: Very clever. Then just do `$('#element').css('background-color').replace(')', ', 0.5)').replace('rgb', 'rgba');` where 0.5 is your alpha level.

Answer (score 3):

What about this algorithm?

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm

You could even create a JQuery plugin that uses that algorithm. I think it would be cool. I don't know if there exists one already.

Answer (score 3):

Purely working with the string you have, you could something like this :

```
var color = '#FF5500';
```

First, extract the two hexadecimal digits for each color :

```
var redHex = color.substring(1, 3);
var greenHex = color.substring(3, 5);
var blueHex = color.substring(5, 7);
```

Then, convert them to decimal :

```
var redDec = parseInt(redHex, 16);
var greenDec = parseInt(greenHex, 16);
var blueDec = parseInt(blueHex, 16);
```

And, finally, get your `rgb()` string as a result :

```
var colorRgb = 'rgb(' + redDec + ', ' + greenDec + ', ' + blueDec + ')';
console.log( colorRgb );
```

And you get as output :

```
rgb(255, 85, 0)
```

Comment: This will work as long as those string begin with one useless character, and have two digit per color -- but if you don't have two digits per color, this will not work anymore, and will need a bit of rework.

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate all three components from the Hex definition, then convert them to decimal. This works:

```
function hex2rgba(x,a) {
  var r=x.replace('#','').match(/../g),g=[],i;
  for(i in r){g.push(parseInt(r[i],16));}g.push(a);
  return 'rgba('+g.join()+')';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/AfVhs/1/