# Tab Opacity Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to apply opacity to jQuery tabs? It works for accordions but I can't get it to work for tabs.

CSS

```
    .ui-tabs{
    background-image: none;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    }

    .ui-tabs-nav{
    background-image: none;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    }

    .ui-tabs-panel{
    background-image: none;
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change only Alpha channel in background-color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794997/change-only-alpha-channel-in-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it with [JQuery `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
var myAlpha = 0.1
$(".ui-tabs").css({ "background-color": "rgba(204, 204, 204, "+myAlpha+")"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.css()`:

```
$(".ui-tabs").css({ "background-color": "rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5)"})
```